# Migrate documents from 2007 to 2013 and maintain version history?

Tags: 2013, migration, version-history

Currently I have a SharePoint 2007 site that I am upgrading to SharePoint 2013. Is it possible to copy the documents from the 2007 site to the 2013 site whilst maintaining version history?

I'd be particularly interested to know about non-code based solutions, but it's not too much of a problem if coding is required.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you allowed to use paid, third paty solutions?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, obviously i'd prefer not to, but I'd like to hear about them anyway so I can make an informed decision :)

Comment: If you are upgrading, why would you have to copy the documents? Wouldn't it just be an in-place upgrade?

Comment: database attach upgrade require you upgrade from 2007 -> 2000 -> 2013 which is quite a process.. It would be easier by simply coping files over if all they need to retain are documents and version history.

Answer (score 0):

Three possible ways of doing this:

1. If you have a licence to SharePoint 2010, try a database attach upgrade on your site collection. Link here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947141.aspx
2. You could attempt to open both of your document libraries in Explorer view and just MOVE the documents. Of course, I have tested this with 2013 libraries where version history is maintained. However you should prefer moving with a developer environment first.
3. Write a server side code on 2007 (since client side service lists.asmx is not good enough to get version history easily - I have tried), and get version history from there, and build up the versions on 2013 via CSOM.